# How can we use transition from a view Controller to a split view Controller?

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

Any possible to include this transition code for split view transitions?

```
    [UIView transitionFromView:self.window.rootViewController.view
                        toView:viewController.view
                      duration:0.65f
                       options:UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal
                    completion:^(BOOL finished){
                        self.window.rootViewController = splitViewController;
                    }];
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can using CATransition class and it's class methods

Comment: can u post some code that we can under stand what is your fix....

Comment: +(CAAnimation *)setAnimation{} Using this class method